# Applications of Integral Calculus - Find Volume of Tent

Tags: calculus

I've the following question - I wrote it in text for your convenience:

> A tent has a base shaped like a square.
>
> It is supported by arches that are in the shape of the curve's $y=-x^2 + \frac{3}{2}$
>    part which is above the $x$-axis. The  unit of the coordinate system is 1 meter.
>
> What is the volume of the tent?

Illustration + question:

[image: question + illustration]

How can I solve this? I feel like there's only **one** given missing, but what's given is enough to solve this.

Comment: It is unclear where is the $x$-axis.

Comment: what is a "shave of a curve" -- I pretty much was sure that you meant "shape", but then - "v" and "p" are not that close on the keyboard...

Comment: yeah I'm confused about that too. but the written question has shape @uniquesolution

Comment: Read again. It says "shave:"

Answer (score 1):

The tent must touch the ground at all boundaries of the square.

Therefore, the square's side length is $\displaystyle 2\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$.

We have the parabolic slice area as $\displaystyle \int_{-\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}}^{\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}}\left(\frac{3}{2}-x^2\right)\,dx=\sqrt{6}$.

The slice has the same area for all $x$ in the square.

Therefore, the tent has volume $\sqrt{6} \times 2\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}=2\sqrt{9}=\boxed{6}$$m^3$

Comment: I think the side of the square should be $2\sqrt\frac{3}{2}$ in the final calculation. The calculation of the area of the slice is accurate since the limits are $+\sqrt\frac{3}{2}$ and $-\sqrt\frac{3}{2}$ but the final multiplication should be with $2\sqrt\frac{3}{2}$ correct?

Comment: oh! yes i agree

Comment: thank you! @user1952500

Comment: I get $\sqrt{3}$ for the side.

Comment: @RafaBudría $x^2-\frac{3}{2} = 0$ implies $x = \pm\sqrt\frac{3}{2}$ and the length of each side is $2\sqrt\frac{3}{2}$ with the axis at $y=0$.

Comment: The arches are in the diagonal.

Comment: @RafaBudría you're right, and this solution will become completely invalid in that case.

Comment: I get $9/4 m$ for the volume

Comment: oh, are they? thank you for the correction:) @RafaBudría

Comment: Np. I am trying to integrate for horizontal slices.

Comment: This integral should become $$2\,\int_{0}^{\frac{\sqrt3}{2}}\left(\frac{3}{2}-x^2\right)\, 2x \,dx = \frac{27}{8}$$ right? How did you get $\frac{9}{4}$ @RafaBudría ?

Comment: I don't get what the integrand means, it's the heigh of the arch for some $x$...

Comment: Added a small solution as the comments are getting tough to handle. I have deleted it in case you want to answer it separately @RafaBudría

Answer (score 1):

We integrate on sections at heigh $y$, from the ground at $y=0$ to the tent's apex at $y=3/2$. The arches, of shape $y=3/2-x^2$, are planted along the diagonals. So, at heigh $y$, the sections are squares having diagonals of length $2x=2\sqrt{3/2-y}$.

By Pythagoras, with $l$ the square's side, $l^2+l^2=(2x)^2=(2\sqrt{3/2-y})^2$. Then, $l^2=3-2y$ is the square's area.

$$V=\int_0^{3/2}(3-2y)dy=3y-y^2|_0^{3/2}=\dfrac{9}{4}m$$